# Display HTTP GET Data in SHINY

Tags: json, http-get, shiny, httr

I have a PostgreSQL database for which I created RESTful Api's using Talend DI that allow me to query tables
Now my question is how to call my Api's in Shiny and display the data received ?

example of http get response :

```
 [{"medical_consultations":{"medical_consultation":[{"id":"1640087","id_consultation":"GFAPAAPA P 834406012009","consultation_date":"07-01-2009","id_center":"APA"},{"id":"1640088","id_consultation":"GFAPAAPA P1079007012010","consultation_date":"08-01-2010","id_center":"APA"},{"id":"1640089","id_consultation":"GFAPAAPA P1098811052007","consultation_date":"12-05-2007","id_center":"APA"}]}}]
```

Ps: I have no problem doing it using 'RPostgreSQL' package in Shiny to connect directly to my database but I prefer to separate it from shiny and that would be by using my web services

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the API all setup then you could do something like this:

```
require(shiny)
require(httr)

url <- "http://httpbin.org/get?"

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput('GETargs',"GET string"),
      actionButton('sendGET','Send')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput('GETresponse'),
      dataTableOutput('table1')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$sendGET, {
    getargs <- input$GETargs

    if( is.null(input$GETargs) ) getargs <- ""

    res                <- GET(sprintf("%s%s",url, getargs))
    output$GETresponse <- renderPrint(content(res))

    output$table1 <- renderDataTable( as.data.frame(content(res)$args) )
  })
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui,server))
```

For example setting the text in the textbox to "param1=value1&param2=value2" sends a GET request to the selected URL. This might not be the way you want to implement this but maybe this gives you some idea on how this can be done.

If i use the example query sting I could for instance access "param1"'s  value by typing:

```
content(res)$args$param1
```

Comment: Worked pretty good, but it renders the data as it is not as a table, How can I put it in a table ?

Comment: You have to build a data.frame or a matrix to render the table from, look at  `?renderDataTable` or `?renderTable`. I updated my answer to put the GET parameters returned in a table.